# Fluid Layout with Floating Fixed Right Sidebar

Tags: navigation, fixed, fluid-layout, hybrid

I'm trying to create a fluid layout with a floated fixed-size right column. If the fixed-size right column div comes after the fluid div, the fixed-size gets pushed down. I'd like to maintain the order of the divs in my html for the responsive layout.

```css
.wrap      { margin: 20px; padding: 20px; background: cyan; }
.main      { margin-right: 220px; background: lightGray;}
.sidebar   { width: 200px; float: right; background: yellow;}
.main,
.sidebar   {  min-height: 100px; }
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="sidebar">Fixed-Width Sidebar is First in HTML</div>
        <div class="main">Fluid Main Content is Second in HTML</div>
    </div>

<div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="main">Fluid Main Content is First in HTML</div>
        <div class="sidebar">Fixed-Width Sidebar is Second in HTML</div>
    </div>
```